# snmpd cannot statfs directory

Tags: 16.04, syslog, snmp

On Ubuntu 16.04, I'm running snmpd for monitoring. In my syslog, I'm seeing the following message every 5 minutes:

```
Sep 23 11:10:11 kvm snmpd[3427]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/debug/tracing: Permission denied
```

The snmp daemon is being run under the snmp user. /sys/kernel/debug has permissions:

```
drwx------ 27 root root 0 Sep 22 21:34 .
```

So, this error makes sense. What doesn't make sense, however, is why snmpd is trying to stat this directory. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following setting is in `/etc/default/snmpd`. The Permission Denied message goes away when I change to `Ls3d` from `Lsd`, so I assume that it is related to log level.

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -p /run/snmpd.pid'
```

I found some information about snmpd log level in [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/310640/reduce-snmpd-logging-verbosity).

Comment: Most newer systems are running systemd, therefore the file which needs the same change is the snmpd.service unit file:
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service`
After you're done editing the file you'll need to reload like this: `systemctl daemon-reload`

Answer (score 1):

This is an older post but it is the first hit on DuckDuckGo so I am going to post a clarification since I've been working on this all morning. I am running Debian 9 with systemd, so you need to edit `/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service` and reload using `systemctl daemon-reload` as stated previously.  You also need to restart snmpd using `systemctl restart snmpd`. You can check the command line used to actually start the service using `systemctl status snmpd`.

The instruction above to change `-Lsd` to `-Ls3d` is incorrect. This option is case-sensitive and `-Ls3d` does nothing. It also doesn't throw an error when used to start the service.  The correct option is `-LS3d`.  From the man page:

```
-Ls FACILITY
Log messages via syslog, using the specified facility ('d' for LOG_DAEMON, 'u' for 
LOG_USER, or '0'-'7' for LOG_LOCAL0 through LOG_LOCAL7).
There are also "upper case" versions of each of these options, which allow the 
corresponding logging mechanism to be restricted to certain priorities of message.

For -LF and -LS the priority specification comes before the file or facility token.
```

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 and it didn't help i'm still getting this errors:
snmpd[2959]: Cannot statfs /sys/kernel/debug/tracing: Permission denied

Comment: Changing the logging level will cause you to no longer see other messages that you might need to see. I'm not looking for a solution like this.

There is some part of the snmpd that is reading the /proc/mounts and doing a statfs() on entries that it finds there. I'm looking for ways to prevent this behavior and have not had luck finding a solution or workaround. For me the problem is worst on hosts that are running docker.